# Не работают стили и скрипт (создание проекта в NetBeans8.1 IDE)

Tags: html5, netbeans

После создания небольшого приложения, которое выводит таблицу (работало корректно, пока все стили и скрипт писались в текстовом редакторе), поставили задачу сохранить их как проект в NetBeans. Вроде, все делаю как надо, а ни стили, ни скрипт не функционируют, подскажите, что не так. Буду признателен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавив проект в netbeans Вы к тому же изменили его структуру. Раньше ведь все валялось в одной папке, так? Соответственно пути к файлам скриптов и стилей, прописанные в index.html стали невалидными. 
Пропишите их соответственно актуальной структуре, например так.

```
<script src="js/tablescript.js">
```

Я думаю Вы достаточно компетентны чтобы справиться со стилями сами после этой подсказки.

Comment: спасибо Вам, помогло